# Read only specific csv files in azure dataflow source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow source, a delimited text dataset that points to a folder containing many csv files.

[image]

So the source reads all the csv files inside the folder2. The files inside folder2 are

```
abc.csv
someFile.csv
otherFile_2021.csv
predicted_file_1.csv
predicted_file_2.csv
predicted_file_99.csv
```

The aim is to read data from only the files like **predicted_file_*.csv** i.e to only read the last three files. Is it possible to add dynamic content in dataset so that it reads specific pattern files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In source transformation, under source options, you can provide the wildcard path with filename prefix to read the required files.

***Example:***

(For debug purpose, I have added column to store the filename to verify the files)

**Source:**

[image]

**Source preview:**

[image]

Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#source-transformation) for more information.